# Does my sentence flow?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

Does my sentence make sense? I want to make sure it flows.

> I'm happy that I had the least amount of cards remaining.

I was told not to use the past tense and the present tense in the same clause. The word “I’m” refers to the present, and the word had refers to the past. I'm just a bit confused with this. My question is a response to me winning a prize.

Comment: Hello Ella,  Can you explain why you have particular concern about this sentence.  What do you mean by "flow".  Why do you doubt that this sentence flows (more doubt than for any other sentence)  What is the context?  Why is important for you to have flow in this sentence.   Asking for improving the phrasing of a sentence isn't a question... so what is your specific question about this sentence?

Comment: Hi James, I was told not to use the past tense and the present tense in the same clause. The word “I’m” refers to the present, and the word had refers to the past. I'm just a bit confused with this.                                               My question is a response to me winning a prize.

Comment: @Ella - *I was told not to use the past tense and the present tense in the same clause* - You have two difference clauses in your sentence, though: **I'm happy**, and **I had the least amount...**

Comment: Not part of your question: I think you had the fewest cards, not the least amount of cards. You don't weigh  cards, you count them.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with using different clauses with different tenses, and in this case to express the fact that "I'm happy (now)" and the reason is "I had the least number of cards (previously, during the game)" it is necessary to use the present tense in the first clause and the past tense in the subordinate clause.

The only time you need to keep the same tense is when two verbs are compounded to form a single verb phrase:

> He cooks and eats a fish every day.

> He cooked and ate a fish yesterday.

> He will cook and eat a fish tomorrow.

You would not say "I cooked and eat a fish"

Otherwise it is common and often necessary to use different tenses in different clauses.